# Why won't SQLSRV show up in PHP Info on XAMPP 7.1.1/PHP 7.1.1?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, web-development-server

I have XAMPP installed but SQLSRV won't show up in PHP info from localhost:81 (81 is the port through which my localhost is accessible).

I downloaded the official SQLSRV drivers from Microsoft and added them to my php.ini like this:

[image]

I also tried the x86 drivers instead, but neither work!

The driver files are located as they should be in C:\xampp\php\ext

Is it just that SQLSRV doesn't work with PHP 7.1.1 yet? Where can I find the latest drivers? I downloaded and used SQLSRV40 and SQLSRV30, neither work at all.

**Note:** SQL Server Native Client 11 is installed

Comment: The fact that you're even trying random architectures suggest you aren't really aware of your system specs and you've possibly haven't installed the support libraries. In any case, I suggest you configure PHP to display errors so at least you have a chance of knowing what's wrong. It also helps to run PHP from the console, where startup errors show up instantly.

Comment: Makes sense. As far as I am aware I have satisfied all the requirements as I can create and connect to a database from the same machine using SQL Server 2016. Stuff like the native client is installed so this should be working...

I don't want to use SQL Server 2016 as I want to sync my accessible SQL databases between machines using Dropbox and trying that on SQLSrv 2016 proved to be a total nightmare. With XAMPP I can boot apache and SQL, both go green and PHP My Admin works just fine... I just won't display SQLSRV even though the extension should be running it

Comment: But, for instance, [you already know](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) that SQLSRV/3.0 will not run on PHP/7.1, there's no point in trying.

Comment: Again makes sense. But I also tried 4.0 which was the correct distribution (I think?) as it contains files like "php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll". Where it says "sqlsrv_7" I assume that this means the file it produced for use with PHP 7. It is a huge assumption but that's why I'm coming here, to try and find out the real answer!

Comment: You'll get some light when you manage to see startup errors.

Comment: If XAMPP says Apache and SQL are running with a green-light, does that mean that there were no start up errors (otherwise Apache should have crashed?) or that some startup errors don't prevent Apache / SQL from starting and get hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from php.ini:

extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

and try again

It should show up in Registered PHP Streams when you view PHP info

Comment: i try to remove that, but the errors still same.. i dont see the driver in phpinfo(). why ? anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and wasted a lot of time trying to fix it. What solved it for me was quite simple:
- I uninstalled XAMPP and reinstalled the **7.0.15 / PHP 7.0.15 version** 
- I added the **x86 drivers** to C:\xampp\php\ext and also to php.ini

At the moment it seems that SQLSRV isn't working with PHP 7.1.1 yet. I hope this helps you out.